# Run .net core application from local IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing asp.net 2.0 core application in visual studio 2017.

Earlier we had the option of Web where we could specify the localhost url to run the application from local IIS.

But with .net core we dont see that option.

Could anyone let me know how can we run this application via local iis.

Thanks

Comment: You have to publish first and then host on IIS. There is no more debugging on IIS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Program running without publish on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910063/asp-net-core-program-running-without-publish-on-iis)